# Hive Query logic and Optimization

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I have data in below mentioned format:

Input

```
**ID     col1     Rank**
ID1      C1_abc      R1_1
ID1      C1_xce      R1_2
ID1      C1_fde      R1_3
ID1      C1_sde      R1_4
ID2      C1_sds      R1_1
ID2      C1_hhh      R1_2
ID3      C1_aaa      R1_1
ID4      C1_asw      R1_1
ID4      C1_eee      R1_2
ID4      C1_ttt      R1_3
```

Output:

```
**ID    col1    col2      col3**
1     C1_abc     C1_xce    C1_fde      
2     C1_sds     C1_hhh    null
3     C1_aaa     null      null
4     C1_asw     C1_eee    C1_ttt
```

I want to achieve this using hive script. I know multiple ways of doing it but needs the most optimized way of doing it as the data volume is large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when rank = 1 then col1 end) as col1,
       max(case when rank = 2 then col1 end) as col2,
       max(case when rank = 3 then col1 end) as col3
from t
where t1.rank in (1, 2, 3)
group by id;
```

The alternative is a multi-way join:

```
select t1.id, t1.col1, t2.col1 as col2, t3.col1 as col3
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.rank = 1 and t2.rank = 2 and t1.id = t2.id left join
     t t3
     on t1.id = t3.id and t3.rank = 3;
```

You may need to try both to see which runs faster.  It could vary based on your data.

Comment: First option works like a charm. Before asking this question i was using 2nd option already but it was not optimized and taking up to 40 minutes to complete. This was got completed with in 60 seconds. Thanks Gordon.